# PHP + MySQL: When I select from two tables, how to define from which table I want to take "id"

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, each with an "id" field. Here are the two tables:

```
news    : id, authorid, datetime, body
authors : id, name
```

I have this select query:

```
SELECT * FROM news, authors WHERE (news.authorid = authors.id) ORDER BY news.datetime DESC;
```

Then, in PHP, I want to use id of the table news. I have this code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    // I want to take news.id, but it gives an error:
    echo $row["news.id"]; // error: "Undefined index: news.id"

    // And when I write only "id", it takes it of authors.
    echo $row["id"]; // this id is authors.id, but I want news.id
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them aliases

```
SELECT news.id AS news_id FROM news, authors WHERE (news.author = authors.id) ORDER BY news.datetime DESC;
```

Or

```
SELECT *, news.id AS news_id FROM news, authors WHERE (news.author = authors.id) ORDER BY news.datetime DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks! +1 because of the asterix

Comment: You shouldn't really use the asterisk though, be specific in which information you are retrieving. At a later date the table schema could grow and you would then be selecting lots of extra columns for no good reason...

Comment: @philm yup you're right. My tech lead (who sits opposite me) keeps saying that as a mantra, that's why I included both examples :)

Comment: Apologies JohnP, my comment was directed at the OP as he seemed to think it was a good idea. I wasn't in anyway trying to preach to you. You're examples are spot on :)

Comment: @philm no problem, I didn't see OPs comment myself, that's why I replied to you ^_^

Answer (score 3):

IN you SQL query, you can use aliases :

```
select table1.id as id_1, table2.id as id_2, ...
```

The columns will be available from PHP using the aliases, and not the names of the columns.

In your case, you'd have :

```
SELECT news.id as news_id, news.authorid, news.datetime, news.body, 
    authors.id as author_id, authors.name
FROM news, authors 
WHERE (news.author = authors.id)
ORDER BY news.datetime DESC;
```

And, in your PHP code, you'd use the aliases :

```
echo $row["news_id"];
echo $row["author_id"];
```

Comment: Thanks! I like JohnP's answer a bit more because of the use of the asterix. However: +1

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitely define the fields you want to retrieve and alias the ambigous ones:

```
select news.id as news_id, news.authorid, news.datetime, news.body, 
    authors.id as authors_id, authors.name
FROM news, authors WHERE (news.author = authors.id) 
ORDER BY news.datetime DESC authors.name
```

Answer (score 0):

user As statement in sql like

```
select news.id as newsid, news.authorid as newsauthorid, authors.id as authorsid ....
```

and in php get as

```
echo $row["newsid"] ;

//

echo $row["authorsid"] ;
```